# Avoid repeating the same query for object list in each Django view

Tags: django, django-views

I have a product list in my site's main menu.
My site's main menu is defined in my base template.

The product list is not hardcoded in template and is queried from DB.
So my base template requires product list to be in the request context of each view.

What is the best way to avoid querieng for product list and putting result into the request context in each view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use template_context_processors. Create file, for example context_processor.py, and write in it method with argument request. Method must return values, in your case, it is product list. Then in settings file in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS option add your file_name.method_name. And in the base html use variable, which was returned.